# How to put item and quantity in a dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I want to show how many quantity remaining in the inventory table in a dropdown list. I can't show the remaining quantity of the inventory

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-lg-4">Material</label>
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMaterial" runat="server" class="form-control" AutoPostBack="true" onselectedindexchanged="ddlMaterial_SelectedIndexChanged" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

And this is the cs to get the inventory

```
void GetMaterials()
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Products.ProductID, ProductName, Inventory.Quantity FROM Products INNER JOIN Inventory ON Inventory.ProductID = Products.ProductID";
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    ddlMaterials.DataSource = dr;
    ddlMaterials.DataTextField = "ProductName" + "Quantity";
    ddlMaterials.DataValueField = "ProductID";
    ddlMaterials.DataBind();
    con.Close();
}
```

I want to look like = grape (6), apple (4) and mango (0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way could be to update your SQL such as

```
SELECT Products.ProductID, ProductName + '(' + convert(nvarchar,Inventory.Quantity) + ')' as ProdInventory FROM Products INNER JOIN Inventory ON Inventory.ProductID = Products.ProductID
```

and then

```
ddlMaterials.DataTextField = "ProdInventory";
ddlMaterials.DataValueField = "ProductID";
```

p.s. untested code.

Comment: what do you see when you just run that query against sql

Comment: It works pretty good, but when selected it only shows the item

Comment: doesn't make sense, it should either work or not work at all. Why would it show the product name? Did you change the DataTextField to ProdInventory?

Comment: You mean as in mango(0)? Wouldn't the inventory.quantity be returned as 0? Please explain what you mean otherwise